# How to use ngx-intl-tel-input library in Angular 15 and above

Tags: angular, ngx-international-phone-number

I want to import library ngx-intl-tel-input to validate phone number with the country code in reactiveForm module and when change country code the phone number.

I want to use ngx-intl-tel-input for phone number vaildate with the country code and set phone number on edit patch.

It's not mandatory to be dependent on ngx-intl-tel-input specific. If any other working for angular 15 and above please help me out.

My versioning details below.

```
 => npm = 8.19.4,
 => node = 16.20.1
 => Angular CLI: 15.2.10
Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1501.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.1.6
@angular-devkit/core            15.1.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.10
@angular/cdk                    15.2.9
@schematics/angular             15.2.10
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.8.4
```

I have tried installing ngx-intl-tel-input-gg(which does shows that it supports angular 15 and 16), angular-phone-number-input. But my requirement is to use the library which smooth installs the dependencies and does not require `npm i some-library -f`(forfully flag) to install it. I don't want to use `-f` flag. Because, it might break the pipelines on development server when deploying the changes because in the `pipelines.yml` it's `npm install` and not `npm install -f`.

**NOTE:** I don't have Angular materials, so I will not be using `ngx-mat-intl-tel-input`.

Comment: `intl-tel-input-gg` installs without any issues, what exact problem do you have?